# Quebrar linha com <img> e <p> dentro de um <ion-button> - IONIC 5

Tags: html, css, ionic, sass

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<ion-grid fixed>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12">

      <ion-button (click)="go('adopt')" class="button" color="dark">
        <img src="./assets/images/pet-shelter.webp" alt="">
        <p>{{ 'HOME.CALL-ADOPT' | translate }}</p>
      </ion-button>

      <ion-button (click)="go('register')" class="button" color="dark">
        <img src="./assets/images/register.webp" alt="">
        <p>{{ 'HOME.CALL-REGISTER' | translate }}</p>
      </ion-button>

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 70px;
}

ion-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
}
```

Gostaria que a imagem ficasse encima ao meio e o texto abaixo, porem eles ficam na mesma linha.

Como eles ficam:
[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thales, utilize uma div para cada elemento para conseguir manipulá-los mais facilmente.

```
<ion-button (click)="go('adopt')" class="button" color="dark">
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="imagem">
      <img src="./assets/images/pet-shelter.webp" alt="">
    </div> <!-- imagem -->
    <div class="paragrafo">
      <p>{{ 'HOME.CALL-ADOPT' | translate }}</p>
    </div> <!-- paragrafo -->
  </div> <!-- content-container -->
</ion-button>
```

Com isso você consegue manipular o CSS utilizando display flex e alinhar os elementos da forma que está querendo.

```
.content-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Só tome atenção com as dimensões da imagem e as dimensões das divs de cada elemento para que nenhum elemento sobreponha ao outro.